# Ejercicio escuchador de eventos: cambiar html

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando modificar el html de las etiquetas h1 cuando paso el ratón por encima. Estoy practicando con el escuchador de eventos, pero no se me aplican los cambios.
Espero vuestras respuestas,

gracias.

CÓDIGO HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="miscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="texto">Pasa por encima para cambiar el html</h1>

</body>
</html>


SCRIPT:

window.onload=function(){

    document.getElementsByTagName("h1").addEventListener("mouseover",cambiarHtml);
}

function cambiarHtml(){ 

    this.innerHTML = "Texto cambiado";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")` devuelve un array de elementos por lo que debes acceder al elemento deseado (en este caso el 0) para añadirle el evento. Si te fijas en la consola te dará el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   document.getElementsByTagName(...).addEventListener is not a function
>       at window.onload (js:26)

Te dejo aquí el código funcionando.

**Edito**: Como bien indica @JDev, el OP desea añadir el evento a todos los `h1`. Para ello te pongo un ejemplo con un `for` sencillo aunque podrías explorar otras opciones como `forEach` o `for in`:

```js
window.onload=function(){
    let h1Elts = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    for(let i=0;i<h1Elts.length;i++){
      h1Elts[i].addEventListener("mouseover",cambiarHtml);
    }
}

function cambiarHtml(){ 
    this.innerHTML = "Texto cambiado";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="miscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="texto">Pasa por encima para cambiar el html</h1>
    <h1 id="texto">Pasa por encima para cambiar el html</h1>
    <h1 id="texto">Pasa por encima para cambiar el html</h1>
    <h1 id="texto">Pasa por encima para cambiar el html</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) más info.

Comment: Ojo, lo requiere para todos los `h1`no solo para el primero. Cambialo por un `forEach`

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Lo cambio.